# Waiting for chained deferreds to finish

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering what would be the best design for chaining Deferreds. Please consider the following snippet:

Component X:

```
_functionRaisingEvent: function()
{
    $.when(this.raiseEvent('myEvent', args)).done(function(args){ // Check for args.cancel });
},

_raiseEvent: function(event, args)
{
    var def = new $.Deferred();

    // Call subscribers of myEvent in different components and pass them args
    // Subscribers possibly make ajax calls

    return def.promise();
},
```

Subscriber Y:

```
_onMyEvent:function(args)
{
    $.ajax(....).done(function(data){ if(data == 1) args.cancel = true;});
},
```

Subscriber Z:

```
_onMyEvent:function(args)
{
    document.getElementById('abx').display = 'block';
}
```

_functionRaisingEvent calls _raiseEvent which fires the callbacks of the subscribers.

What I’d like to achieve is, that the callback of done in _functionRaisingEvent is only executed after all subscribers finished.

Should I pass the subscribers their own Deferred as argument and use pipe? Is the any best practice or design pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key would be changing this part

```
_raiseEvent: function(event, args) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    //Call subscribers...
    return def.promise();
}
```

...to return a collection of deferreds, not just one, and then passing these as a collection to `$.when`. Since `$.when` doesn't accept collections, and insists on objects being passed as separate arguments, the common workaround is to call `$.when` via the `apply()` method inherited by all functions.

```
_raiseEvent: function(event, args) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    //Call subscribers... - let's assume each returns an AJAX object
    var result_subscr1 = call_subscriber_1();
    var result_subscr2 = call_subscriber_2();
    return [def.promise(), result_subscr1, result_subscr2];
}
```

...and then changing your current `$.when()` to

```
$.when.apply(null, this.raiseEvent('myEvent', args)).done(...
```

The result of each deferred is then passed to your `done()` callback, in the order the objects were passed to `$.when()`.